# Show that $C_n$ complement is hamiltonian for all $n\geq5$

Tags: graph-theory

I need to show that $C_n$ complement is hamiltonian for all $n\geq5$, so for now I have this:

We know that $C_n$ is 2-regular for all $n$, so $C_n$ complement is $n-k-1$-regular, as $k=2$ then $C_n$ complement is $n-3$-regular, so $d(v) = n-3$ for all $v \in V(C_n(complement))$ and $n-3 \geq n/2$ then $C_n$ complement is hamiltonian

is this ok? thanks!

Comment: It doesn't quite work for $n=5$ since the stated inequality fails for that value. Nevertheless, you can exhibit a Hamiltonian cycle in the complement of $C_5$, and your proof is correct.

Comment: Yes, this looks fine.

Comment: @ParclyTaxel I have a question, if $n=5$ if I say $\frac{n}{2} = 2$? wont this be the case?

Comment: No, that idea is plainly false.

Comment: Ok! Thanks for your time!